# How to encyrpt a TEXT field column in mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption, text

I am designing a customer care application and would like to encrypt the case request field which is using a TEXT type field. Also if I need to change the type of field which type would you suggest a BLOB or a varbinary? The maximum length users use to enter a case request is around 2,000 characters.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it?  Who are you protecting it from?

Comment: I would like to encrypt this field so to conform with the GDPR Regulations.